# Add user id to bash history

Tags: linux, bash, history, redhat

Currently when I do history I get:

```
  996  05/13/14 10:37 ls-l
  997  05/13/14 10:37 ls -l
  998  05/13/14 10:37 chmod 700 hosts.txt
  999  05/13/14 10:37 tail -5 .bash_history
 1000  05/13/14 10:37 tail -10 .bash_history
 1001  05/13/14 10:38 hisotry
```

Is it possible to change the mechanism to that when it becomes:

```
  996  username1 05/13/14 10:37 ls-l
  997  username1 05/13/14 10:37 ls -l
  998  username2 05/13/14 10:37 chmod 700 hosts.txt
  999  username3 05/13/14 10:37 tail -5 .bash_history
 1000  username1 05/13/14 10:37 tail -10 .bash_history
 1001  username4 05/13/14 10:38 hisotry
```

I tried editing the `PROMPT_COMMAND` but was unable to get the result I want.

The scenario that I am dealing with is several users sudo to another user and each user runs several commands. What I need is track which user ran which command.

Answer (score 3):

History reports only commands executed by current logged in user.
You may use `su -c history username` to check history for other users on your system.

Comment: `sudo -u username history` is probably better than doing `su`

Comment: In some linux distro, sudo is not installed/configured by default.

Comment: I am trying using this when I am checking the history of a shared account. The users sudo into this account to execute commands. I am trying to see which user executed which commands

Answer (score 2):

You can abuse the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` variable to accomplish this. Add the following to your `.bashrc`:

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT="$USER %m/%d/%Y %H:%M "
```

Comment: I tired this but this doesn't seem to add one user id to all the commands in history. What i need it if a user sudo to another id and run a command. The history should have that user who sudoed in the history.

Comment: The shell doesn't know if another user used `sudo` to start it; it can only record the name of the user under whose ID the shell is running.

Comment: `who am i` allows me see the user who is sudo into the user. But it add that user to all commands in history and not just to the commands executed by the user.

Answer (score 0):

you can run:

```
history | sed "s/  / $UID /"
```

and if you want to make a command for that:

```
alias histuid='history | sed "s/  / $UID /"'
```

though I'm not sure why you'd want such a thing, as the history command is a shell builtin that can only return the history of the current shell session for the current shell's user.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simpler solution that worked for me. In your `/etc/bash.bashrc` on Ubuntu 18.04, add the following to the end or modify if it exists.

[Solution]

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="`whoami` %m/%d/%Y %H:%M "
```

[Result]

```
1987  {omitted} 07/13/2018 - 20:10:56 history | tail -19
```

**Note** that previous entries will be updated. `{omitted}` shows the username. `whoami` in single quotes used in a bash command script.